# Including logging.conf in setup.py?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, distutils, data-files

In my `package_name` subdirectory (one below "setup.py") I have a "logging.conf" file.

How do I include it in my setup?

#### Attempt

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib

data_files=[(path.join(get_python_lib(), package_name),
                     path.join(path.dirname(__file__), package_name, 'logging.conf'))
```

Preferably it should be something simple like:

```
data_files = [(package_name, path.join('.', package_name, 'logging.conf'))]
```

#### Error

> error: can't copy 'c': doesn't exist or not a regular file

Comment: Can you paste the complete traceback please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you want to include `logging.conf` within your package distribution? Use the `package_data` argument to `setup()`:

```
setup(
    name = "package-name",
    packages = ["packagename"],
    package_data= {
        "packagename": [
            "resources/foo.bar",
            "resources/static/css/*",
            "README.md",
            "logging.conf"
        ]},
    ...
    )
```